# Object #<HTMLDivElement> as jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get a `#<HTMLDivElement>` as a jQuery object?

I need to do the following: I have a list of div's with the class contents. So I iterate over it until I find the one with the additional class: "test"

here is my code:

```
$.each( $(".contents"), function( key, value ) {
    if (value.hasClass("test"))
    {
        alert("got it");
    }
});
```

I'm getting the exception: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'hasClass'`

Comment: Just pass it to the [jQuery constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element).

Comment: Why don't you use some selector like `$(".contents.test").each(alert.bind(window, "got it"))`? Or `$(".contents").filter(".test")`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `each()` function gives you `DOM` object and you have to convert it to `jQuery` object. You can pass `value` to `$` jQuery function to convert it to jQuery object.

```
$.each( $(".contents"), function( key, value ) {
    if ($(value).hasClass("test"))
    {
        alert("got it");
    }
});
```

You do not need to iterate through each and simplify it like

```
elements = $(".contents.text")
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not to do it simpler with:

```
$(".contents.test"). ...
```

Here jQuery will select element that has both `"contents"` and `"test"` classes set.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xfErG/

Comment: this is not possible because in this example its called test but in my real case its always a other name

Comment: @gurehbgui So what? Do it with `$(".contents." + myClassName)`.

Answer (score 0):

The main jQuery function can accept a DOM Element as its argument.

```
var foo = jQuery(HTMLElementNode);
```

The following two lines of code have the same end result:

```
var foo = jQuery('#foo');
var foo = jQuery(document.getElementById('foo'));
```